# Transfer Learning with a Faster RCNN Inception Resnet | Why new checkpoints get saved for each step after a first checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have ~24000 images in widescreen format 1920x384 and want to do transfer learning by training six classes of objects available in my image data set onto a **faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco** network, pretrained on the COCO dataset, which I downloaded from the tensorflow [model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

I use the corresponding config file from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config), which I changed (despite the pathes for my training and validation `*.tfrecords` in the following way

```
num_classes: 6          # adjustment to my number of classes
image_resizer {
  keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
    min_dimension: 288  # rescaling to 75% of the minimum dimension of the images in my dataset
    max_dimension: 1440 # rescaling to 75% of the maximum dimension of the images in my dataset
  }
}
```

Starting the training works fine

```
Starting Training...
WARNING:tensorflow:Forced number of epochs for all eval validations to be 1.
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting train_steps: None
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting sample_1_of_n_eval_examples: 1
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting eval_num_epochs: 1
INFO:tensorflow:Maybe overwriting load_pretrained: True
INFO:tensorflow:Ignoring config override key: load_pretrained
WARNING:tensorflow:Expected number of evaluation epochs is 1, but instead encountered `eval_on_train_input_config.num_epochs` = 0. Overwriting `num_epochs` to 1.
INFO:tensorflow:create_estimator_and_inputs: use_tpu False, export_to_tpu False
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x0000013C8555B4A8>, '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
WARNING:tensorflow:Estimator''s model_fn (<function create_model_fn.<locals>.model_fn at 0x0000013C85559AE8>) includes params argument, but params are not passed to Estimator.
INFO:tensorflow:Not using Distribute Coordinator.
INFO:tensorflow:Running training and evaluation locally (non-distributed).
INFO:tensorflow:Start train and evaluate loop. The evaluate will happen after every checkpoint. 
Checkpoint frequency is determined based on RunConfig arguments: save_checkpoints_steps None or save_checkpoints_secs 600.
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:80: parallel_interleave (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.interleave_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(...)`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py:1165: sparse_to_dense (from tensorflow.python.ops.sparse_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Create a `tf.sparse.SparseTensor` and use `tf.sparse.to_dense` instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py:148: batch_and_drop_remainder (from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.batching) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.data.Dataset.batch(..., drop_remainder=True)`.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\predictors\heads\box_head.py:93: calling reduce_mean (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) with keep_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
keep_dims is deprecated, use keepdims instead
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py:2236: get_or_create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[360]], model variable shape: [[24]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1536, 360]], model variable shape: [[1536, 24]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/biases] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[91]], model variable shape: [[7]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [SecondStageBoxPredictor/ClassPredictor/weights] is available in checkpoint, but has an incompatible shape with model variable. Checkpoint shape: [[1536, 91]], model variable shape: [[1536, 7]]. This variable will not be initialized from the checkpoint.
WARNING:root:Variable [global_step] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\core\losses.py:345: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\myuser\Projects\models\research\object_detection\core\losses.py:345: softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:

Future major versions of TensorFlow will allow gradients to flow into the labels input on backprop by default.

See `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`.

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py:112: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2019-10-11 08:11:42.427791: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2019-10-11 08:11:43.075302: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1432] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.38
pciBusID: 0001:00:00.0
totalMemory: 15.90GiB freeMemory: 15.26GiB
2019-10-11 08:11:43.075684: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible 
gpu devices: 0
2019-10-11 08:11:43.524992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-10-11 08:11:43.525209: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-10-11 08:11:43.525324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-10-11 08:11:43.525795: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0001:00:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.5189617, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.5189617, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.6828
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.6828
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.5950212, step = 100 (59.456 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.5950212, step = 100 (59.456 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.00219
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.00219
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.8909993, step = 200 (49.914 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.8909993, step = 200 (49.914 sec)
....
....  # lines skipped
....
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.04283
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 2.04283
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.2713771, step = 1100 (48.933 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.2713771, step = 1100 (48.933 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1162 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1162 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:25:05
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:25:05
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2019-10-11 08:25:07.753227: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible 
gpu devices: 0
2019-10-11 08:25:07.753427: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device 
interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-10-11 08:25:07.753615: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-10-11 08:25:07.753741: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-10-11 08:25:07.754137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0001:00:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1162
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1162
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Loading and preparing annotation results...
INFO:tensorflow:Loading and preparing annotation results...
creating index...
index created!
INFO:tensorflow:DONE (t=0.17s)
INFO:tensorflow:DONE (t=0.17s)
creating index...
index created!
Running per image evaluation...
Evaluate annotation type *bbox*
DONE (t=11.83s).
Accumulating evaluation results...
DONE (t=5.48s).
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.709
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.981
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.904
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.605
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.728
 Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.794
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1 ] = 0.768
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10 ] = 0.774
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.775
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = 0.700
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100 ] = 0.787
 Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100 ] = 0.835
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:40:41
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:40:41
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1162: DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP = 0.70930076, 
DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large) = 0.7941316, DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium) = 0.7282758, 
DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small) = 0.6049327, DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU = 0.98051566, 
DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU = 0.9042774, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1 = 0.7676365, 
DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10 = 0.77410305, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 = 0.7745228, 
DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large) = 0.8347223, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium) = 0.78670675, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small) = 0.69985116, 
Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss = 0.0749631, Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss = 0.048301302, Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss = 0.096785806, Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss = 0.0898837, Loss/total_loss = 0.30993363, global_step = 1162, learning_rate = 0.0003, loss = 0.30993363
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 1162: DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP = 0.70930076, 
DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large) = 0.7941316, DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium) = 0.7282758, 
DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small) = 0.6049327, DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU = 0.98051566, DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU = 0.9042774, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1 = 0.7676365, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10 = 0.77410305, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 = 0.7745228, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large) = 0.8347223, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium) = 0.78670675, DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small) = 0.69985116, Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/classification_loss = 0.0749631, Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/localization_loss = 0.048301302, Loss/RPNLoss/localization_loss = 0.096785806, Loss/RPNLoss/objectness_loss = 0.0898837, Loss/total_loss = 0.30993363, global_step = 1162, learning_rate = 0.0003, loss = 0.30993363
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 1162: C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1162
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 1162: C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1162
```

So as you can see the training performs 1162 steps and saves a checkpoint the way it should (I assume since the 600s of key `_save_checkpoints_secs` are over. Now the aspect starts, which I do not understand. Instead of now starting to count another thousand of steps until the next checkpoint, it immediately saves a checkpoint for the next step 1163

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1163 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1163 into C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:42:22
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-10-11-06:42:22
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
2019-10-11 08:42:23.981937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1511] Adding visible 
gpu devices: 0
2019-10-11 08:42:23.982106: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] Device 
interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-10-11 08:42:23.982290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:988]      0 
2019-10-11 08:42:23.982405: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1001] 0:   N 
2019-10-11 08:42:23.982784: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14763 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0001:00:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1163
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from C:\\191011_faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_transfer_learning\model.ckpt-1163
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
...
... # continues with saving checkpoints for all upcoming steps
...
```

and this goes on similarly for step 1164 and any following step. The question is: Why does the training start to save checkpoints at every step **AFTER** it did the first checkpoint after a certainly higher number of steps before?

Additional info: I did the training already with a ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco network, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into the same problem, I found a solution [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5139#issuecomment-418963839):

The problem may be, that the validation run takes too long. 600s is simply not enough and after just one training step a new validation is performed. This way, the training would take forever since the majority of the time would be occupied with validation.

To make it work, one has to add an additional parameter to

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)
```

in the `models/research/object_detection/model_main.py` file. Add either (both do not work) the parameter `save_checkpoints_steps` **or** `save_checkpoints_secs`. One can either choose the amount of steps or the amount of time until a checkpoint is created and a corresponding validation is performed.

For example:

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir, save_checkpoints_steps=2000)
```

will save a checkpoint and run a validation every 2000 training steps.

Comment: Nice, great finding. Legit user apparently!